# How do you handle routing when your application uses client and server side mvc frameworks?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, design-patterns, routes

I'm working on an application that is using both Angularjs and Asp.net MVC. One thing that I'm confused about is how exactly I should handle URL's and where should I put my partials?

For example, if I'm trying to create a modal pop up with angularjs like below:

```
$scope.popup = function (feedback) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/what/path/goes/here',
        controller: 'angularjscontroller',
        size: 'lg',

    });
}
```

- Do I put my html partials in the regular view folder for my serverside app?
- If I need a particular partial can I use the same /Controller/controllerfunction pattern that I would use if I was strictly using a server side mvc application?
- How does angular handle something like a layout.html file if I only want a specific partial?

Everything that I've found so far seems like they strictly use one or the other and not both.

Comment: pro tip: use a gulp/grunt plugin to add all views to a angular templateCache. Then you only need 1 request to the server to fetch all views (which are automatically minified). On the url's: usually the server side will start with a /api/vX prefix, so it's usually possible to have two completely separate applications for front end and back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I put my html partials in the regular view folder for my serverside
>   app?

I do.  I create a separate controller for serving up the views, separate from the controller that serves up the data.

> If I need a particular partial can I use the same
>   /Controller/controllerfunction pattern that I would use if I was
>   strictly using a server side mvc application?

Sure.  As long as that controller only returns a partial view.

> How does angular handle something like a layout.html file if I only
>   want a specific partial?

I may not understand the question here but it doesn't handle that.  You need to give it the appropriate template.